# Python - Convert Application Layer Info Into IP Layer Info

Tags: python, httprequest, packet-capture

In Python, I have all the information about a web request that I can get, by intercepting and blocking a web request. I have the URL, the URL of the site requested the next URL, Get/Post, navigation type, resource type, etc..., in a dictionary like:

```
Info = {"url": "https://www.google.com",
             ....}
```

I need to convert this into packets of the structure IP(TCP(RAW(...))) and send them on (likely with Scapy's `send/sendp/sr/srp`), with a modification to the dest IP. I can't intercept packets directly, as I cannot find a way to block, modify, and then resend the packets on.

How, in Python, would I go about converting my application level web request into packets?

I am using Windows 10 and Python 3.8, and I can use any 3rd party module.